# Approximate Integrration by series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am following a Maths text on approximate integration using series expansion but I am stuck on a step in one worked example. It's probably really simple as the text doesn't explain the step, it just assumes the reader should see it but I don't.

I get the general principle that for an Integral that can not be solved traditionally you can try and expand the component functions into power series and see if that allows you to solve.

e.g. for $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}cos(x) dx$ you can multiply the power series of cos(x) by $\sqrt{x}$ and then integrate to get an approximate answer.

However, I gather this only works for converging series.  That's all good.  However, the book then details a diverging series which they fix by taking out a factor.

I understand the straightforward factorisation, but I don't see where the circled section comes from.  I know you can represent a function as a series of powers so that:

f(x) = a + bx + cx$^2 + dx^3 + ...$ but why does it follow that the circled section takes the form it does?
[image: Image from text book]
Can someone explain it to me?  Thanks!

Comment: Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{1-q} = (1-q)^{-1} = 1+q+q^2 + q^3 + \ldots
$$
for $|q|<1$. Then substitute $q= -\frac{1}{x^3}$

Comment: Thank you Matti.  I am glad I spent the time asking the question.  I had to look up binomial expansion. I think I will go back and study that in a bit.

My question is solved now.